# Popper.js won't load

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I wish to use a dropdown menu. When I click it it does not work and the following message appears in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
```

I googled and found a way to install popper, but when I try to run the install command:

```
PM> Install-Package popper.js
```

The visual studio package manager shows the following message:

```
Package 'popper.js.1.12.9' already exists in project '<ProjectName>'
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: You've clearly got Popper in your project already. Are you sure you've referenced it correctly, and loaded it *before* Bootstrap?

Comment: Where do I check the load order? I am not sure if I have done that correctly.

Comment: In your `<head>` section of your HTML.

Comment: There is a reference to popper.js in the Packages.Config file, that's why you are receiving the error message..at one time it was installed, or it is still installed and you are looking at how to "include" it not install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This must be the reason looking to your problem you are saying . The order of including script file should be like this :

1> jquery

2> popper js

3> Bootstrap js

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Work like a charm for me..! :)