# Popper.js not initializing on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, popper.js

When I try to initialize Popper.js like below, nothing happens.

```
 $().ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
```

However if I apply the same code to a button, it magically works as soon as it is pressed.

```
$('#randomButton').click(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
```

How can I fix this problem?
My imports already are in the order suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552728/popper-js-wont-load) post.

Comment: Try to pass `document` to the function  like this  `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: I've already tried that as well, no difference

Comment: Maybe it's because it has to be associated with an element or something but you can always call the button click inside page load.

Comment: @iamdlm I just tried that, to no avail.

Comment: With that said and the comment about the debugger it's seems that the library is taking more time to load than the code getting executed. I would add a delay on page load before calling the click and see if that works. If it works maybe you can check if the library is loaded before using the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code to my main.js file fixed it:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}, 500);
```

I guess what happened is that I tried to initialize the tooltips before the elements with the tooltips could even be loaded via ajax.